# Writing attributes to an two dimensional array

Tags: java, loops, nested, multidimensional-array

This is my first time posting here, but I am in dire need of some Java expertise (or perhaps just another set of eyes).

I am writing an ArrayList of objects (Result) to a 2d array. I am trying to use a nested loop. Basically each row is entered and the first column is checked to see if it matches any of the in the ArrayList with the same 'team' attribute. if it finds a match it processes it and removes it, it continues on until the end of the list and then exits to repeat the process on the next row.

It seems to work, however when it finds a match and processes it (inclding removing it) it doesn't seem to continue looking in the inner loop for more matches.

Can anyone please tell me why it is not continuing to loop?

Here is my code:

```
private String[][] addScores(String[][] dataTable)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < dataTable.length; r++)
        {
            Iterator<Result> itr = outcomes.iterator();
            Result temp = new Result();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                temp = itr.next();
                //If a team is found.
                if (dataTable[r][0] == temp.team)
                {
                    //Increases matches played.
                    dataTable[r][1] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataTable[r][1]) + 1);
                    if(temp.result == WIN)
                    {
                        dataTable[r][2] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataTable[r][2]) + 1);
                    }
                    if(temp.result == DRAW)
                    {
                        dataTable[r][3] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataTable[r][3]) + 1);
                    }
                    if(temp.result == LOSE)
                    {
                        dataTable[r][4] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataTable[r][4]) + 1);
                    }
                    //removes entry.
                    itr.remove();

                    break;
                }
            }                   
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're storing the team names and win/draw/lose records is very awkward. How about this:

Create a Team class

```
public static class Team
{
    String name;
    int win;
    int draw;
    int lose;
}
```

Put those teams in a hash map (using the team name as the key):

```
Map<String,Team> map = new HashMap<String,Team>( );
```

You would add new teams to the map with:

```
map.put( team.name, team );
```

Then, when you iterate through your results, all you need is:

```
Iterator<Result> itr = outcomes.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    Result temp = itr.next();
    Team team = map.get( temp.team );

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I tried a HashMap before, but if the team name is the same then the put method would simply find the key with the same name and replace it, ergo the team name must be uniques.

Comment: So then you first try to grab the value associated with the key "team name" and if then only insert a new entry if the retrieval fails.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that String[][] dataTable is a **R * 4** 2d array  ,and there is not any  indexoutofboundException on your log.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.No, there doesn't seem to be any indexoutofboundExceptions, it seems to just iterate through exactly the number of elements in the 2d array. It is something to do with that blasted inner loop!

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking out of the while loop. Remove the break after itr.remove();

You are also comparing addresses of strings instead of contents (when you use ==), so you only have matches where the first entry in the row is the exact same String object as in the outcomes. The == will not be true if two different String objects have the same contents.

Also, since you are iterating over an ArrayList, use a for-each loop to clean up your code a bit.

```
for(int r = 0; r < dataTable.length; r++)
    {
        for(Result result : outcomes)
        {
            //If a team is found.
            if (dataTable[r][0].equals(result.team))
            {
                //Increases matches played.
                dataTable[r][1] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataTable[r][1]) + 1);
                if(result.result == WIN)
                {
                    dataTable[r][2] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataTable[r][2]) + 1);
                }
                if(result.result == DRAW)
                {
                    dataTable[r][3] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataTable[r][3]) + 1);
                }
                if(result.result == LOSE)
                {
                    dataTable[r][4] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataTable[r][4]) + 1);
                }
            }
        }                   
    }
```

Finally, you don't need to return anything for this method, as arrays (or double arrays) are objects and this method can just be used for its side affects.

Comment: Hmm, I tried, but it sill exits the loop upon finding a match. Does the removal of the element, inside the if statement, cause the condition of the while loop to be met?

Comment: It has worked!!

I cannot express how much I appreciate your help! I have spent a good 2 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

you break statement is actually break the while loop not the if condition, so it wont loop the while loop. remove the break;